# Get City Name from Reverse Geocoding with latitude and longitude

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-maps, xml-parsing, reverse-geocoding

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=39.952853,32.901470&sensor=false

In this xml url, I couldn't get data from area which is explained in the below.

```
<long_name>Altınevler Mahallesi</long_name>
```

I'm using asp.net c#.  Could you help me with this?

This is the code I tried to get the data from xml

```
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.Load(
    "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=39.952853,32.901470&sensor=false"
    );

XmlNodeList xNodelst = xdoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("entry");

foreach (XmlNode xNode in xNodelst)
{
    label1.Text += "read";
}
```

Comment: Would you please post the code you're written to try to get the data?

Comment: of course i edited my post.

Comment: What if you change the selection line into `XmlNodeList xNodelst = xdoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("result/address_component/long_name");`?

Comment: But there are many adress_componet how could i get spesific one

Comment: Could you be more specific about what result you are expecting? `XmlNodeList xNodelst = xdoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("result/address_component/long_name[. = 'Altınevler Mahallesi']");` would return two results for that long_name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved my question if anyone wants know be my guess. Solution indicated in the below.

Thank you

```
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xDoc.Load("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=" +coordinate+"&location_type=ROOFTOP&result_type=street_address&key=YOURAPIKEY");

        XmlNodeList xNodelst = xDoc.GetElementsByTagName("result");
        XmlNode xNode = xNodelst.Item(0);
        string adress = xNode.SelectSingleNode("formatted_address").InnerText;
        string mahalle = xNode.SelectSingleNode("address_component[3]/long_name").InnerText;
        string ilce = xNode.SelectSingleNode("address_component[4]/long_name").InnerText;
        string il = xNode.SelectSingleNode("address_component[5]/long_name").InnerText;
```

so you can pull anydata for google maps.